# DisplayReplyAllForm is showing popup blocker alert in IE and Edge

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to open reply email using DisplayReplyAllForm, it is showing popup blocker alert in IE and Edge.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyAllForm(
    {
        'htmlBody' : emailBodyHtml,
        'callback' : function(asyncResult)
        {
            console.log('reply mail with asyncResult.value ==> ' + asyncResult);
        }
    });
```

I am trying to execute this code in a function which will be called by button onclick handler.

Error View :
[image]

**This is stopping us from app store submission**. What is the fix for this?

Comment: How are you calling this? Keep in mind that browsers determine if a popup should be blocked based on how it is triggered. It needs to be triggered directly from user interaction (i.e. from an `onClick` event).

Comment: We are calling inside onclick event only. Seems because of asynchronous call displayreplyallform

Comment: look at the test code where we are calling directly. https://gist.github.com/NehaU93/dc98666a1c028f4f5e3eeb77ae24f0b7

Comment: @MarcLaFleur any update?